# combine select with sum

Tags: mysql, select, sum

I would like to select * from a table and have only certain columns show a sum result at the bottom, see example.

[image: example output]

I have tried UNION but there has to be the same number of columns in both queries.

Comment: Add blank columns to the beginning of the sum query so you can combine it with union.

Answer (score 0):

Combine the sum using `UNION`, and add empty columns to make it the same number of columns.

```
SELECT rd, dte, vs, venu, h_a, res, g_f, g_a, g_d, pts
FROM yourTable
UNION ALL
SELECT '', '', '', '', '', '', SUM(g_f), SUM(g_a), SUM(g_d), SUM(pts)
FROM yourTable
```